# Forcing developers under limited Windows user accounts

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts, restrictions

I'm currently in negotiations with a company as to why a machine **not** on a domain network **and with full admin privileges** is necessary for developers to work fully.

I'm looking for evidence to specifically support/contradict this e.g.

- Programs can't be run that use systems software i.e. XAMPP/WAMP, VPN software etc.
- Programs can't be installed or updated.

Comment: Maybe this questions is better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can allow Users to install programs.  Thats something that can be configured.  Both points can be handled by slight group policy changes.  There is **NO** reason for developers to have `Administrator` rights.

Answer (score 2):

As a developer I always used user account for secure daily work. This can be achieved with corporate policy, because people do not like limits and it will be hard for the first time. When I implemented limited user policy, I had so little work as admin in 100 workspace office, month before it was constant virus nightmare. For some cases if people still need elevated priveleges for their tasks. I used my own version of runas that was limited to run specific applications. Take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/
Also, you can untie user rights by setting Power User and playing with policy editor.

Answer (score 1):

1. A developer should be in full control of their development environment. They need to be able to install, uninstall, configure and use any software that's needed to develop working code. Having a limited account means they have less control over their machine and might not be able install or run critical software.
2. Sometimes, the software a developer uses requires it to be started with admin privileges. For example, if you are developing an Azure cloud service and want to test it from your Visual Studio, you need to run Visual Studio as an administrator, or IIS will not start.
3. 99% of the software a developer needs gets at least one update they don't have yet but need. Often, such an update requires admin privileges to even install.
4. Developers are less likely than normal users to misuse their admin privileges, because they are far more computer literate and know how to handle a computer properly.

Another angle is cost: a developer that needs to ask an admin for a password every so often is a huge timesink for both the developer and the admin. And if he does not get that password, he could very well be blocked from progressing on his code.

A common reason to restrict access is that the software should be able to run on a limited account as well. this can easily be done on a virtual machine.

see also: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14967/risks-of-giving-developers-admin-rights-to-their-own-pcs

Comment: 1. No, a developer needs full access to his/her devoloping environment and nothing else. System admins install software, not developers!
2. No, if you are a developer, you show you know little about user rights. Users can be given proper rights to use any software, and still be limited where they don't need access.
3. Assumptions! Where are your sources? Updates can be remotely pushed if and when needed by a System admin.
4. BIG assumption that has no statistical background. Software developers are known to be the worst users. They think they know it all, but a lot of them have no clue.

Comment: @Jakke I'm 100% sure that if you'll ask this on programmers or superuser SEs, you'll get an entirely different response that does agree with me. it depends on who you ask. if I google "programmers admin rights", I get page after page of people who agree with me.

Comment: This is the ever lasting discussion between System Admins and Developers. There are very few system admins who will agree with you! Don't you think it's best to leave responsibilities to the experts? Developers are no system admins and the other way around. You wouldn't want a system admin to come and tell you how to develop your code either. The fact that developers don't see the problem in having admin rights (which you'll see in most of your Google results), proves to a system admin that they shouldn't have it.
All you need is a good system admin that can give you the tools to do your job.

Comment: I have worked on both ends, as a developer and as a system admin. I never had any issue working with limited accounts as a developer because I always got the tools I needed to do my job. If you're working in a corporation, you have to be a team player and not only think about your own convenience. I've worked with hundreds of developers and though there are the ones that could have admin rights, the ones that don't deserve them far outnumber them!
Even if you have to write hardware drivers, you can develop them on a limited networked computer and test them on a standalone open computer.

Comment: I don't want this to become a war between sysadmins and devs, but I'll say that it depends on the size of the company and the developer department. A small company with less than 7 or 8 developers likely won't have the resources to assign a fulltime systemadmin to handle permissions and manage a update pusher system. And sometimes, an automatic update pusher is somewhat overkill. Especially if you have developers working on different projects in need of different tools. I have 4 developing coworkers with most working in pairs on different projects. We don't all use the same tools.

Comment: @Jakke If you have a specialized company working on a commercial large-scale product meant for consumers or a complete sector with more than 10 developers on the same project with the same tools and in need of the same computer setup, I agree that it makes sense to have a single person (and in larger companies, an entire department) to manage developer accounts and user accounts for the entire company. But again, it mostly depends on your company size.

Comment: With that I can agree. As an independent developer, or a small company, you often don't have the same amount of departments with their individual expert teams. The bigger the company, the more policies, tools and budgets you will have in place and the more security and restrictions for the employees.

Comment: @Nate Of course IT operations encompasses much more then what you make it out to be. Other than that I have nothing to say, and in face, I'm going to flag this questions as unproductive.

Answer (score 0):

Developers are not system admins with good reasons. A lot of them don't know what makes a computer tick and handing out admin rights will give a lot of system admins a lot of extra work! (Speaking out of 15 years experience).
Developers need full rights in the areas where they need it and nowhere else. It takes a little time to configure everything correctly, but it's certainly not impossible.

Just give your users the proper rights, put them in custom groups that have necessary rights to perform their daily tasks.
I have been working as a developer in a banking environment as well where they treat security on ALL LEVELS as a top priority. The only people in the company who have full admin rights were the system admins. Unlike most companies, even top level managers (like CEO, CFO etc) are not allowed to do just whatever they please.

But again, you need to be good as a system admin and spend some time to make a good configuration for your developers so they can do their job properly without any complaints. Worst case scenario, they can always perform their tests in a controlled test environment where they might have some additional rights to evaluate what customers with full rights may experience. These test environments can even be virtual machines that have limited or no network access and are easily restoreable.